# Assign another name/alias for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, typedef

I am trying to give `std::vector` a different name like `MyVector`, so I did following typedef

```
typedef std::vector<float> MyVector<float>;
```

However, visual studio complains on `MyVector` that "MyVector is not a template"

How do I assign `std::vector` another name?

I have may `MyVector` in my code which is essentially `std::vector`, so I just want to equal `std::vector` with `MyVector` so I don't have to change all the `MyVector` into `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using MyVector = std::vector<T>;
```

That will allow you to use it like this:

```cpp
MyVector<float> vec = stuff;
```

Where `vec` will be a `std::vector<float>`.